# Dashcode development - Emulator safari not able to load the page

Tags: ios-simulator, iphone, dashcode

I am using iOS simulator 4.3 for Dashcode 3.0.2. When I run the application I the simulator safari throws an error and cannot load the page. On the other hand the page is easily loaded on desktop browser. The url of the application formed uses `localhost` with the port number. However, when I replace the `localhost` word in the url with the ip address of my system, it works perfectly on the simulator safari.

I am blocked please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.local` keyword was deleted from **Bypass proxy** settings, I added it back and it works great now.

Comment: Thats great; Thanks, and i've been wasting my entire half day in finding this.